# How to add asp button to dynamically genreated control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, postback

I have a control that overrides Render() and creates its HTML dynamically,
here is a simiplified version of it:

```
 public class CReportBillReadings : Control
    {           
            protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
            {
                base.Render(writer);
                writer.Write(Html);
            }  

                private string Html
                {
                    get
                    {                   

                        // render result table
                        var sb = new StringBuilder();             
                        sb.Append("<ul id=\"export\"><li><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"table_to_pdf(); return false;\"><img src=\"/resources/images/pdfIcon16x16.gif\" /></a></li></ul><div class=\"clear\"></div>");
```

And so on.

What it actually does is draw a table according to the given data.

I want to add an asp button to the html ,
so that I can register to its event on the server side.

The only ways I found to do this is:

1. Add this button to a place holder - not applicable here because the entire HTML is generated dynmically.
2. Add a jquery button - but I need to handle the event on the server side.

I read about a promising lead here:
http://www.evagoras.com/2011/02/10/how-postback-works-in-asp-net/

But I still can't figure out how to use it- because in the examples I've seen the button is still declared in .aspx and not dynmically in the code.

Comment: Do you want to create buttons on several rows?

Comment: No , just one button above the table

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit your control from `Button` control instead of `Control`. In this case you will have events and all other properties of button. And you can also render table in overrided `Render` method.

Comment: But than if I click anywhere on the control - it will fire the click event, I only want to catch the event if the user clicks on a sepecific button which is part of the control.